# Calculate difference of columns of two tables

Tags: mysql

I am a newbie in mysql and php and not so experienced yet in making complicated queries. 
Thanks of some users on stackoverflow below query is now successfully working. 
the last bit I am missing now is to include calculating the difference between total from q1 and costs from q2 in this query. Thanks for your help in advance. cheers

```
Select * from ( SELECT invoice.eventid, invoice.invoiceno, event.clientid, client.clientid, clientname, 
gross_amount, vat, total, due 
FROM client, invoice, event 
WHERE event.eventid = invoice.eventid 
AND event.clientid = client.clientid) 
as q1

inner JOIN (SELECT event_ma.eventid, 
salary.staffid, Sum(cost_hour * Time_to_sec(Timediff(hours, pause))) / 3600 AS costs 
FROM salary 
JOIN event_ma ON salary.staffid = event_ma.staffid GROUP BY event_ma.eventid) 
as q2  
ON q1.eventid = q2.eventid 

GROUP BY q1.eventid
```

Comment: Don't use "SELECT *". Write out the names of the columns you actually want returned... "SELECT q1.id, etc...". Then the solution to your problem may magically occur to you!

Answer (score 0):

Add the calculated field in your primary `SELECT`-statement:

```
Select *, (q1.total - q2.costs) AS difference
from ( SELECT invoice.eventid, invoice.invoiceno, event.clientid, client.clientid, clientname, 
gross_amount, vat, total, due 
FROM client, invoice, event 
WHERE event.eventid = invoice.eventid 
AND event.clientid = client.clientid) 
as q1

inner JOIN (SELECT event_ma.eventid, 
salary.staffid, Sum(cost_hour * Time_to_sec(Timediff(hours, pause))) / 3600 AS costs 
FROM salary 
JOIN event_ma ON salary.staffid = event_ma.staffid GROUP BY event_ma.eventid) 
as q2  
ON q1.eventid = q2.eventid 

GROUP BY q1.eventid
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you. And so easy at the end.